# Gibbs within Collapsed Gibbs?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

I have a model with variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}$. I would like to sample it within a larger MCMC chain using:

$(X_{1}, X_{2}) \sim P(X_{1}, X_{2})$

$(X_{3}, X_{4}) \sim P(X_{3}, X_{4} \mid X_{1}, X_{2})$

I don't actually know how to do either of those, so I would like to sample it as:

$X_{1}' \sim P(X_{1} | X_{2})$

$X_{2}' \sim P(X_{2} | X_{1}')$

$X_{3}' \sim P(X_{3} | X_{1}', X_{2}', X_{4})$

$X_{4}' \sim P(X_{4} | X_{1}', X_{2}', X_{3})$

The paper "Metropolis-Hastings within Partially Collapsed Gibbs Samplers" [1] suggests that it is possible to use a M-H step within a Partially Collapsed Gibbs sampler. Since Gibbs sampler is just a special case of M-H, I'm hoping that the above sampler can be considered as a special case of "M-H within PGS".

Does the above sampler work? Are there any example of similar samplers?

[1] http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3217